# How to Create a link to Current Tab Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

when i go through the url:www.domain.com/#ratings ,the rating tab should be open ,right now it showing the current tab in the url ,but not working for linking the tabs

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.tabs a').click(function () {
            switch_tabs($(this));
        });
        switch_tabs($('.defaulttab'));
    });

    function switch_tabs(obj) {
        $('.tab-content').hide();
        $('.tabs a').removeClass("selected");
        var id = obj.attr("rel");
        $('#' + id).show();
        obj.addClass("selected");
    }
</script>
<ul class="tabs">
    <li>
        <a href="#movies" class="defaulttab" rel="movies">Tutorial</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#ratings" rel="ratings">Comments</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="contentbox">
    <div class="tab-content" id="movies">movie tab</div>
    <div class="tab-content" id="ratings">rating tab</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you create a demo for it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I think, you are complicating a lot of things, but keeping your code, I've fixed your problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
$(function(){
  var hash = window.location.href.split('#').pop();
  var allowed = ['hello', 'world'];
  if(allowed.indexOf(hash) == -1) hash = allowed[0];
  switch_tabs($('a[href=#'+hash+']'));
});
```

Comment: I was selecting the tab itself not the link. Non should be fine.

Comment: How to redirect the user to default tab [#movies] ,if the link id is wrong typed #ratiee instead of #ratings ..

Comment: You can store `window.location.href.split('#').pop()` in another var and compare it against allowed one. If not allowed set it to default.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.tabs a').click(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $('.tabs a').removeClass("selected");
            $this.addClass('selected');
            switch_tabs($this.attr('href'));
            return false;
        });
        var anchor;
        var hash = $('a[href="' + location.hash + '"]');
        if(hash.length > 0){
            anchor = hash;
        }
        else{
            anchor = $('.defaulttab');
        }
        anchor.click();
    });

    function switch_tabs(hash) {
        $('.tab-content').hide(); 
        $(hash).show();   
        location.hash = hash;
    }
```

Comment: it works ,thanks. but the current selected tab is not showing... once see the old code and your code in html page .You will find that ..

Comment: Yes, it wasnt adding current class if selected by browser's hash. Now, I've edited the code. Also it "redirects the user to default tab [#movies] ,if the link id is wrong typed #ratiee instead of #ratings" , no need to create a list for that :)

Answer (score 0):

With switch_tabs(window.location.hash); ?

for example:

```
    $(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
    alert(window.location.hash.split('#').pop());
        switch_tabs(window.location.hash);
    });
```

when hash change call your function